# Is there a way to find out automatically if a third party library has been updated

Tags: ios, github, cocoapods

Im using a couple of libraries I found on `GitHub`, and I was wondering is there a way to know when a third party library used in an app has been updated? For example, a bug fix.

Must we continuously visit the users repository to find out for our selfs, or does using a dependency manager like Cocoa Pods have this functionality?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocoa pods allows you to manage third party library, one feature it has it is `pod outdated` which checks for new releases of library's and also check if a project has new commits

more info on cocoa pods, [see link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261124/what-is-cocoapods)

example 1 (library with releases only):

say you have AFNetwoking in your project using cocoapods with the following syntax: pod "AFNetworking" if you wanted to just check for updates do `pod outdated`, or to update the library if there are releases you would do `pod update`

example 2(library with most recent commits):

there times were you want to get most recent commits regardless of if it stability. On cocoapods you can do `pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git'`. this gets the most recent commit on git

Answer (score 1):

CocoaPods handles this. Just type `pod install` every once in a while. It will fetch all available updates for you... I've been using CocoaPods for a long time without problems... You can even create private pods or development pods if you need to.

Comment: Thank you for this, cocoa pods seems to be the way to go!