# Does adding a framework to a project folder increase binary size?

Tags: xcode

I've had an issue with frameworks and absolute paths in the past. If I link (without copying to project folder), frameworks like facebook, then every time I go to a different computer I have add the framework back in.

Should I just drag it to the project folder, then add?

If I place the framework in the project folder, does that increase the binary size?

Follow up question: Sometimes when I add a framework to the project folder, it still has the absolute path, so every time I launch the project, I get a missing framework compile error. So I have to remove the reference and drag back in. How can I avoid it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use dependency manager like [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) instead. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261124/what-is-cocoapods/22261196#22261196) for more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app size should not be affected by simply copying framework from other location to project directory.

Also the compiled objects links to framework binary, most times framework is not embedded in app file. But it really depends on what framework you are dealing with, in Xcode 6, you may need to embed a framework in Embedded Binaries (with signing) to your project, and thus app size is affected.

Comment: Response to follow up question, I would normally 1. Remove reference of existing framework from project 2. Copy framework to project dir 3. Drag framework to project 4. When I compile I get a warning of redundant framework search path 5. Remove redundant framework search paths. It is similar to what you have done, but I don't error.