# Working process of pod install command in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoapods

I have one doubt about cocoapod. Nowadays we are using dependency manager cocoapod for adding libraries to our project.
For example I added  `pod 'Alamofire'` command in podfile and i run `pod install` command in my terminal.Then automatically added Alamofire library to our xcode project.This is working fine.

But my doubt is we are mentioned  only `pod 'Alamofire'` in podfile, then how to download this exact library from this single line command? What is the process done in background when i run `pod install` command?

Comment: I hope this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22261124/what-is-cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

When you mention just the name of the repository in podfile. It automatically checks the latest version of the library present on GitHub and downloads it.

Here is the detailed log of what happens when you install a pod.

```
Analyzing dependencies

Updating spec repositories
Updating spec repo `master`
  $ /usr/bin/git pull
  Already up-to-date.


Finding Podfile changes
  - AFNetworking
  - HockeySDK

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
Resolving dependencies for target `Pods' (iOS 6.0)
  - AFNetworking (= 1.2.1)
  - SDWebImage (= 3.2)
    - SDWebImage/Core

Comparing resolved specification to the sandbox manifest
  - AFNetworking
  - HockeySDK

Downloading dependencies

-> Using AFNetworking (1.2.1)

-> Using HockeySDK (3.0.0)
  - Running pre install hooks
    - HockeySDK

Generating Pods project
  - Creating Pods project
  - Adding source files to Pods project
  - Adding frameworks to Pods project
  - Adding libraries to Pods project
  - Adding resources to Pods project
  - Linking headers
  - Installing libraries
    - Installing target `Pods-AFNetworking` iOS 6.0
      - Adding Build files
      - Adding resource bundles to Pods project
      - Generating public xcconfig file at `Pods/Pods-AFNetworking.xcconfig`
      - Generating private xcconfig file at `Pods/Pods-AFNetworking-Private.xcconfig`
      - Generating prefix header at `Pods/Pods-AFNetworking-prefix.pch`
      - Generating dummy source file at `Pods/Pods-AFNetworking-dummy.m`
    - Installing target `Pods-HockeySDK` iOS 6.0
      - Adding Build files
      - Adding resource bundles to Pods project
      - Generating public xcconfig file at `Pods/Pods-HockeySDK.xcconfig`
      - Generating private xcconfig file at `Pods/Pods-HockeySDK-Private.xcconfig`
      - Generating prefix header at `Pods/Pods-HockeySDK-prefix.pch`
      - Generating dummy source file at `Pods/Pods-HockeySDK-dummy.m`
    - Installing target `Pods` iOS 6.0
      - Generating xcconfig file at `Pods/Pods.xcconfig`
      - Generating target environment header at `Pods/Pods-environment.h`
      - Generating copy resources script at `Pods/Pods-resources.sh`
      - Generating acknowledgements at `Pods/Pods-acknowledgements.plist`
      - Generating acknowledgements at `Pods/Pods-acknowledgements.markdown`
      - Generating dummy source file at `Pods/Pods-dummy.m`
  - Running post install hooks
  - Writing Xcode project file to `Pods/Pods.xcodeproj`
  - Writing Lockfile in `Podfile.lock`
  - Writing Manifest in `Pods/Manifest.lock`

Integrating client project
```

Please refer to this [Link](https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/cocoapods-under-the-hood/) for a detailed version of how CocoaPods work.